# Cordova Ajax request

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter, cordova, cross-domain

hello i'm using ajax request in Apache cordova 9.0.0 to php codeigniter, everythink works with the browser but when i emulate with cordova it doesn't work.
Code in Cordova :

```
$.ajax({
            method: 'get',
            url: baseUrl + 'Cartography/Boutique/' + it,
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data) {
                var code = '';
                for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                    traitement...;
                }
                $("#listeBoutique").html(code);
                $('.boutique').DataTable();
            },
            error: function() {
                alert('Impossible de charger les données');
            }
        });
```

My code in Codeigniter

```
public function Boutique($it)
{
    $this->load->model('Boutique_model', 'boutique');
    $data =$this->boutique->get_Boutique_Itineraire($it);
    echo json_encode($data);
}
```

php file header

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, OPTIONS");
header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0");
header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", false);
header("Pragma: no-cache"); 
header("Content-Type: application/json");
```

Comment: what is `cordova` ?

Comment: Apache Cordova is an open-source mobile development framework. It allows you to use standard web technologies - HTML5, CSS3, and JavaScript for cross-platform development.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit your question accordingly. You should include the errors you are getting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved !!!
Just install the latest version of WebView  on the Android device